# How to test if another class method is called within a method in python?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

I have the following structure:

```
ClassB():
   def foo():

Class A():
   def __init__(self, B):
       #some initialisations
   def method1():
       #complex logic
       B.foo()
```

I am trying to write a unit test method1 and would like to test if foo is called once or not.
How I can achieve this? What should I mock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Mock for `B`, pass it to the constructor of `A` and check if the function was called once.

You can write the Mock by yourself. E.g.:

```
class B_Mock():
    def __init__(self):
       self.foo_calls = 0

    def foo(self):
        self.foo_calls += 1
```

And than check the attr `foo_calls` of your B_Mock instance with `assert`

Answer (score 3):

## Edited

Based on the further information provided by OP, a rework on the answer was done.

### Code

The code below has been tested locally with Python3.8.3 on CentOS 8. Run `python3 -m unittest` to see the test result.

Functional code(sub.py):

```py
class B():                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def foo(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
class A():                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def __init__(self, B):                                                                                                                                                                                         
        self.b = B                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    def method1(self):                                                                                                                                                                                             
        self.b.foo()
```

Test code(test.py):

```py
from unittest import TestCase                                                                                                                                                                                      
from unittest.mock import patch                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
from sub import A, B                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
class Test(TestCase):                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def test_A(self):                                                                                                                                                                                              
        with patch('sub.B.foo') as mock_foo:                                                                                                                                                                       
            a = A(B)                                                                                                                                                                                               
            a.method1()                                                                                                                                                                                            
            mock_foo.assert_called_once()
```

Basically the test code tries to mock the `B.foo` method and checks if the method has been called EXACTLY ONCE when `A.method1` is invoked.

### Test Explanation

1. `a = A(B)` line does not call `B.foo`
2. `a.method1()` line calls `B.foo`

In total, `B.foo` is called exactly once so `mock_foo.assert_called_once()` will pass. If any of the arguments above turns out to be invalid, the assertion will fail. In case you just need to check that `B.foo` has been called at least once, use `mock_foo.assert_called()` instead.

For details of the mock system, I suggest to read [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: Are you sure it's called twice inside the patch block? `assert_called_once` indeed checks for exactly one call.

Comment: @xiao, I cant just call A(), I should be passing B to it as A(B), should I be passing a mock of B?

Comment: Ok. As to your question - you can construct an instance of `B` and pass it as parameter to `A()`. If that is not possible, you can indeed mock `ClassB` instead of `ClassB.foo`, and use `classb_mock.return_value.foo.assert_called...` instead.